# failing to load weights into model XCeption-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I make the same model, I load the weights. It had worked before but now it does not. Maybe I am stupid but I am thought I checked everything.

```
def make_model(trainable = False):
xception = Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=input_shape)
xception.trainable = trainable

inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='xception_input')

x = xception(inputs, training=False)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='swish', name='xception_int', trainable=True)(x)
x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
outputs = Dense(17, activation='softmax', name='xception_output')(x)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)

return model
```

then I load the weights.

```
model.load_weights('models/xception2_weights.h5')
```

It has different things it says at the end of the error message. On Mac it says:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32,) and (3, 3, 32, 64) are incompatible
```

on Windows:

```
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

from what it says on the Mac, I guess it has something to do with the XCeption part. I had used load_weights in the same way successfully before I don't know why it is like this now.

If anyone can help, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I identified that when you create the model via tf.keras.applications.Xception as a functional model, has a different shape than including tf.keras.applications.Xception a Sequential model.

It also happens if you remove the top layer, adding a new classifier and then you return back to the original Xception shape with a Dense(1000) output.

If your initial model was generated with a different classifier, you added more layers and went back, it will also mismatch. Please check the axis of the original model and this new one and compare the shapes.